# SVG still tabable even with focusable set to false?

Tags: svg

Even though I've set `focusable` to `false`, with this SVG in a web page every single path is focusable. How can I completely disable tab focus for it?

```html
<svg width="11" height="18" viewBox="0 0 11 18" focusable="false">
    <path d="M9.05599 17.3333C8.13551 17.3333 7.38932 16.5871 7.38932 15.6667C7.38932 14.7462 8.13551 14 9.05599 14C9.97646 14 10.7227 14.7462 10.7227 15.6667C10.7227 16.5871 9.97646 17.3333 9.05599 17.3333Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
    <path d="M7.38932 8.99999C7.38932 9.92046 8.13551 10.6667 9.05599 10.6667C9.97646 10.6667 10.7227 9.92046 10.7227 8.99999C10.7227 8.07952 9.97646 7.33332 9.05599 7.33332C8.13551 7.33332 7.38932 8.07952 7.38932 8.99999Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
    <path d="M9.05599 3.99999C8.13551 3.99999 7.38932 3.2538 7.38932 2.33332C7.38932 1.41285 8.13551 0.666656 9.05599 0.666656C9.97646 0.666656 10.7227 1.41285 10.7227 2.33332C10.7227 3.2538 9.97646 3.99999 9.05599 3.99999Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
    <path d="M0.722656 15.6667C0.722656 16.5871 1.46885 17.3333 2.38932 17.3333C3.3098 17.3333 4.05599 16.5871 4.05599 15.6667C4.05599 14.7462 3.3098 14 2.38932 14C1.46885 14 0.722656 14.7462 0.722656 15.6667Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
    <path d="M2.38932 10.6667C1.46885 10.6667 0.722656 9.92046 0.722656 8.99999C0.722656 8.07952 1.46885 7.33332 2.38932 7.33332C3.3098 7.33332 4.05599 8.07952 4.05599 8.99999C4.05599 9.92046 3.3098 10.6667 2.38932 10.6667Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
    <path d="M0.722656 2.33332C0.722656 3.2538 1.46885 3.99999 2.38932 3.99999C3.3098 3.99999 4.05599 3.2538 4.05599 2.33332C4.05599 1.41285 3.3098 0.666656 2.38932 0.666656C1.46885 0.666656 0.722656 1.41285 0.722656 2.33332Z" fill="#CFCCD6" focusable="false"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focusable is obsolete and most browsers ignore it these days. You should now use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). Specifically tabindex="-1" should make things

> not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation

```html
<svg width="11" height="18" viewBox="0 0 11 18">
    <path  d="M9.05599 17.3333C8.13551 17.3333 7.38932 16.5871 7.38932 15.6667C7.38932 14.7462 8.13551 14 9.05599 14C9.97646 14 10.7227 14.7462 10.7227 15.6667C10.7227 16.5871 9.97646 17.3333 9.05599 17.3333Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
    <path  d="M7.38932 8.99999C7.38932 9.92046 8.13551 10.6667 9.05599 10.6667C9.97646 10.6667 10.7227 9.92046 10.7227 8.99999C10.7227 8.07952 9.97646 7.33332 9.05599 7.33332C8.13551 7.33332 7.38932 8.07952 7.38932 8.99999Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
    <path  d="M9.05599 3.99999C8.13551 3.99999 7.38932 3.2538 7.38932 2.33332C7.38932 1.41285 8.13551 0.666656 9.05599 0.666656C9.97646 0.666656 10.7227 1.41285 10.7227 2.33332C10.7227 3.2538 9.97646 3.99999 9.05599 3.99999Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
    <path  d="M0.722656 15.6667C0.722656 16.5871 1.46885 17.3333 2.38932 17.3333C3.3098 17.3333 4.05599 16.5871 4.05599 15.6667C4.05599 14.7462 3.3098 14 2.38932 14C1.46885 14 0.722656 14.7462 0.722656 15.6667Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
    <path  d="M2.38932 10.6667C1.46885 10.6667 0.722656 9.92046 0.722656 8.99999C0.722656 8.07952 1.46885 7.33332 2.38932 7.33332C3.3098 7.33332 4.05599 8.07952 4.05599 8.99999C4.05599 9.92046 3.3098 10.6667 2.38932 10.6667Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
    <path  d="M0.722656 2.33332C0.722656 3.2538 1.46885 3.99999 2.38932 3.99999C3.3098 3.99999 4.05599 3.2538 4.05599 2.33332C4.05599 1.41285 3.3098 0.666656 2.38932 0.666656C1.46885 0.666656 0.722656 1.41285 0.722656 2.33332Z" fill="#CFCCD6" tabindex="-1" ></path>
</svg>
```